# several audio HW devices, but no sound and zero entries in gnome-control-center

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  Audio has worked fine for a long time, using a usb sound card.  Recently, I started having issues (unable to play any sounds, or at least once unable to adjust system volume).  Note my system also has sound out via the video card, and the motherboard (I have never used either one) - but `gnome-control-center`'s list of output devices (as well as input-devices) is blank.

How can I triage this?  Hopefully, how can I get the settings app to show the cards, and the system to play audio?

`dmesg` & `lsusb` show the relevant USB device. It appears (?) to be recognized correctly as a sound card as seen in `aplay`.

```
$ sudo aplay -l 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
# ... more HDMI's
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  # the motherboard, *I believe*
card 2: Device [USB Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  # the USB card, I believe
$
$
$ lsusb | grep -i audio
Bus 005 Device 010: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
```

but nothing at all here
[image]

and apps trying to use a sound device error out
[image]

I believe my system uses `pulse-audio` (but am pretty n00b here); in the past I could run the following w/ the intended effect:

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master 20%-
    ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection terminated
    amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: Connection refused
```

Comment: as in OP, apps (such as VLC) attempting to open a sound device fail - however I just noticed that simulatneously *firefox*/youtube CAN play sound.  This at the *same time* as the symptoms (no devices in settings, vlc errors).  FF is obviously opening the sound device via some other mechanism?